# I need to populate only active records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to lookup child collection in mongodb using moongose in node.js but it will lookup all child records, i want to lookup only active records.

Parent Collection is Users
Child Collection - Post which contains post published by user and have a user_id as refrence of Users collection. I tried below query but no luck

**User Collection Sample :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584016e28880811461000007"),
    "fname" : "Test",
    "lname" : "user",
    "email" : "test@user.com",
},
{
    "_id" : ,
    "fname" : "Test2",
    "lname" : "user2",
    "email" : "test2@user.com",
}
```

**Post Collection Sample :**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5863aed8cafb42674600000e"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("584016e28880811461000007"),
    "title" : "Post 1",
    "is_deleted" : false

},

{
    "_id" : ,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("584016e28880811461000007"),
    "title" : "Post 2",
    "is_deleted" : true

}
```

**Query I tried :**

```
Users.collection.aggregate([
{ $lookup: {from: "Posts", localField: "_id", foreignField: "user_id", as: "Posts"} },
{ $match : { $or : [{"Posts._id" : {$exists : true}, "Posts.is_deleted" : false}] }},
{$project: {fname: "$fname", lname : "$lname", email : "$email", "publishedPosts" : {$size : "$Posts"}}}

])
```

**Result i got from above code :**

```
[
    {"fname" : "Test", "lname" : "user", "email" : "test@user.com", "publishedPosts" : 2},
    {"fname" : "Test2", "lname" : "user2", "email" : "test2@user.com", "publishedPosts" : 0}
    ]
```

**Result Expected :**

```
[
{"fname" : "Test", "lname" : "user", "email" : "test@user.com", "publishedPosts" : 1},
{"fname" : "Test2", "lname" : "user2", "email" : "test2@user.com", "publishedPosts" : 0}
]
```

it lookup all post, whther is_deleted is false or true

Please help me with some similar query which will work for me

Comment: please provide sample documents from Users and Posts collections, and the expected output

Comment: @felix Please check question, i edited it for you

Comment: @felix i am extremly sorry but by mistake i type wrong expected result. Now, it is fine

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work fine now

Answer (score 1):

The $match stage you're using is wrong. The first condition ( `{"Posts._id" : {$exists : true}` ) is useless because each document has to have an _id field ( see [mongodb _id field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) for details ).

Update: Do the $match stage before $lookup for better performances. Lookup from Posts to Users, then unwind Users and group documents for the sum

this query return the result you're expecting:

```
db.Posts.aggregate([
       {
          $match:{
             is_deleted:false
          }
       },
       {
          $lookup:{
             from:"Users",
             localField:"user_id",
             foreignField:"_id",
             as:"Users"
          }
       },
       {
          $unwind:"$Users"
       },
       {
          $group:{
             _id:"$user_id",
             lname:{
                $first:"$Users.lname"
             },
             fname:{
                $first:"$Users.fname"
             },
             email:{
                $first:"$Users.email"
             },
             publishedPosts:{
                $sum:1
             }
          }
       }
    ])
```

output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584016e28880811461000007"), "lname" : "user", "fname" : "Test", "email" : "test@user.com", "publishedPosts" : 1 }
```

Comment: But it will not return user who never publish any post. We need to show user grid with number of post they publish. If there is no post than need to show 0

Answer (score 0):

you can try this , it working

shop collection

```
{
name:"shop1",
status:true,
_id : ObjectId("583d0c1f2bd2cbdb117053c5")
}

{
    name:"shop2",
    status:false,
    _id : ObjectId("583d0c1f2bd2cbdb117053c6")
    }
```

order collection

```
{
orderNo:1,
price:100,
product:"product1",
shop:ObjectId("583d0c1f2bd2cbdb117053c5")
}
```

try this

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "shop",
              localField: "shop",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "shopData"
            }
       },
       { $match : { $or: [ { "shopData.status": true}] } }

    ])
```

result :

```
[{
orderNo:1,
price:100,
product:"product1",
shop:[{
name:"shop1",
status:true,
_id : ObjectId("583d0c1f2bd2cbdb117053c5")
}]
}]
```